# image masking to Black area+iphone sdk

Tags: ios5, cgimage

Is there any way to mask the some image into particular portion of the another image.
I have an image like this :-

[Image 1](http://pixabay.com/en/old-black-triangle-historic-letter-39437/)
 and I want to mask the another [image 2](http://www.highresolutionpics.info/wp-content/uploads/images/Flower-Wallpaper-flowers-249402_1024_768.jpg) into the black area of the image 1.

IS it possible.If yes then please tell me how is it possible.

I know i can mask the image like :-[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136195/why-does-my-image-mask-make-my-image-black-where-the-mask-is-white)  But i will alow me to mask the whole image.I want to mask the image into particular portion of the image.

Thanks in advance